# Pass multiple different HTML parameters for a Blazor Component - custom List/Table Component

Tags: .net, templates, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to create a custom ListView that wrap the children with something common (and a few logic to disable them). However the children contents are **unknown and different for each child** and is managed by the parent.

Input (from, say, `Index.razor` and the component is `MyList.razor`):

```html
<!-- Other code -->

<MyList>
    <Child Title="Paragraph">
        <p>May have any HTML content</p>
    </Child>
    <Child Title="Link">
        <a href="://example.com">Example Link</a>
    </Child>
    <Child Title="Custom HTML">
        <div>Could be anything in here</div>
        <button onclick="this.OnButtonClicked">Click Me</button>
    </Child>
</MyList>
```

The result:

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="child">
        <p>Row 1: Paragraph @*Title here*@</p>

        <div class="row-content"> @*HTML content here*@
            <p>May have any HTML content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <p>Row 2: Link @*Title here*@</p>

        <div class="row-content"> @*HTML content here*@
            <a href="://example.com">Example Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- More -->
</div>
```

I have tried [templated components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components) but the template is fixed for all chidden. [Dynamically-rendered ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent) would require me to make a component class for each child which is not very desirable. Is there any solution to my question?

---

This is my best attempt so far but I do not know how to pass the `RenderFragment`s to the children:

```html
<app-board>
    @{
        var i = 0;
    }

    @foreach (var row in this.Rows)
    {
        var z = i;

        <fieldset class="board-row" disabled="@(this.CurrentStep < z)">
            <board-col>
                <span class="step-num">@(z)</span>
                <span class="step-title">@(row.Title)</span>
            </board-col>
            <board-col>
                @(row.Html)
            </board-col>
        </fieldset>
    }
</app-board>
```

```cs
public partial class AppBoard
{

    [Parameter, AllowNull]
    public IReadOnlyList<AppBoardRow> Rows { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int CurrentStep { get; set; } = -1;

    public record AppBoardRow(string Title, RenderFragment Html);

}
```

I don't know how I can use it in `Index.razor`:

```html
<AppBoard>
    <!-- What's here? -->
</AppBoard>
```

Comment: Why don't you use RenderFragmanet?

Comment: @AlirezaK I am trying to use it, but how do I pass these parameters from the parent?

Comment: @AlirezaK see my edit. I added my attempt, in the case of `RenderFragment`, I don't know how I can pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with simple "Child Content" components.

#### MyList

```
<div class="list bg-secondary p-2">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

#### MyListChild

```
<div class="child bg-dark text-white p-2 m-3">
    <p>Row @(this.Row): @this.Title </p>
    <div class="row-content">
        @ChildContent
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Title { get; set; } = "No title Provided";
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public int Row { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<MyList>
    <MyListChild Row=1 Title="Paragraph">
        <p>May have any HTML content</p>
    </MyListChild>
    <MyListChild Row=2 Title="Link">
        <a href="http://example.com">Example Link</a>
    </MyListChild>
    <MyListChild Row=3 Title="Custom HTML">
        <div>The last time this button was clicked is @Message</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.OnButtonClicked">Click Me</button>
    </MyListChild>
</MyList>

@code {
    private string Message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    private void OnButtonClicked()
        => this.Message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

I use manual numbering here because, while you could create a system within MyList which cascades an object to get numbers automatically, you are not in control of the render process.  There is no guarantee that the child components will be created or rendered in the sequential order in the markup.  So I've "kept it simple".

I've added some extra CSS so you can see the result better:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I followed the sample of [TabSet and Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0). So turned out I didn't even need `CascadingValue` for it to work (rendering I mean, I still need it for the `CurrentStep` in my specific case). So... I am still a bit confused about _why_ it works...

Comment: UPDATE: finally I found the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#child-content-render-fragments). So `ChildContent` is a "magic" property. Now I finally understand! I thought it was some magic of `CascadingValue` that let me render the whole HTML thing. Turned out it simply take the whole block with custom child items.

Comment: Light Bulb moment.  The Razor compiler knows about `ChildContent`.  The other important thing to understand is the content runs in the context of the parent component.  It's compiled into a method in the parent that matches the `RenderFragment` delegate pattern and then assigned to the `ChildContent` parameter of the child component.

Answer (score 1):

> how to pass the RenderFragments to the children:

To insert the content provided by the parent component in a child component, a feature called Render Fragment is used. An example to explain its details.

First a parent component as follows:

```
@page "/ParentComponent"

<h1 class="text-danger">Parent Child Component</h1>

<ChildComponent Title="This title is passed as a parameter from the Parent Component">
    A `Render Fragment` from the parent!
</ChildComponent>

<ChildComponent Title="This is the second child component"></ChildComponent>

@code {

}
```

Now, the child component as follows:

```
    <div>
    <div class="alert alert-info">@Title</div>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @if (ChildContent == null)
        {
            <span> Hello, from Empty Render Fragment </span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>@ChildContent</span>
        }
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

The Title public property, which is decorated by the Parameter property, enables the setting of a specific value by the component containing the ChildComponent.
Another public parameter is also defined here, this time it is of the special RenderFragment type. It can access the content that is set in the parent component of ChildComponent among its tags. Also, if this content is not set by the parent component, such as the second time the ChildComponent is placed on the page, a default content can be displayed by checking that it is null.

I think the problem with your code is that you have to define the parameter as the `RenderFragment`.

Comment: Sorry I think I am dumb today, but how do you pass the rows content? I assume now we have 3 parts: `Index.razor`, `ParentComponent.razor` and `ChildComponent.razor`. I understand the latter two but how do you pass the `ChildComponent`s **in `Index.razor`**? Note that `ParentComponent` does not know the content beforehand.

Comment: I think you have to use cascading parameters for this.

Comment: Please excuse my slowness, I read the Cascading parameters doc and I cannot understand what it's meant for or how it can solve my problem. Could you kindly provide an example? Thank you

Comment: Well I finally figured it out... Somehow. Honestly I do not really understand why it works but it works now using Cascading parameters. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. I apologize that I saw your comment late.

Answer (score 0):

Render Fragment with a parameter `RenderFragment<T>`. This provides a context of type T for the children.

Parent Component: (Add your own html etc). I use `TItem` here to clarify its purpose.

```cs
@typeparam TItem

@foreach(var item in Data)
{
    @ChildContent(item)
}

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

This will iterate over the list and provide a `context` of type TItem for `ChildContent`.

##### Note: A renderfragment is a delegate. When you use `<T>` this is saying the delegate has a parameter of type `T` by default called `context`

Each child component needs to have its own

```
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public Renderframent ChildContent { get; set;}
```

#### Usage

```
<ParentComponent Data=myList >
    <ChildComponent1 Title="Paragraph">
        <p>May have any HTML content</p>
    </ChildComponent1>
</ParentComponent>

@code {
    private List<ListItem> myList;
}
```

Anywhere inside `ParentComponent` you can refer to the current item as `context`. If your Item has a property of `Name` for example you can use `context.Name`.

You ChildComponent in this case are not aware of TItem however the `context` will be available in the markup area of the composing component.

#### Clever things you can do from here:

Your child components can have the TItem passed in:

```
@typeparam TItem

@ChildContent(Item)

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildContent { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public TItem Item { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

#### usage

```
<ParentComponent Data=myList >
    <ChildComponent1 Title="Paragraph" Item=context>
        <p>May have any HTML content</p>
    </ChildComponent1>
    @context
</ParentComponent>
```

This presents a minor problem though you will have a nested context. To get around this you need to rename at least one to be unique.

```
<ParentComponent Data=myList Context="parentContext" >
    <ChildComponent1 Title="Paragraph" Item=parentContext>
        @context.Name       //
        @parentContext.Name // Both valid here
        <p>May have any HTML content</p>
    </ChildComponent1>
    @parentContext.Name
</ParentComponent>
```